# xcode UITests check if the test is running on real devices

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38)

is there a way to detect if UITests is running on real devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this information from the `ProcessInfo` class:

```
if let simulatorName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME"] {
    print("Running on \(simulatorName) simulator")
} else {
    print("Running on device")
}
```